# SQL Print departments that have employees

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables `departments` and `employees`.

The `department` table has as primary key `department_id`. The `employees` table has as foreign key `department_id`. I want to print all departments that have employees.

[image]

I've tried using a syntax as, but it's not good.

```
SELECT 
    departments.department_id, employees.department_id 
FROM 
    departments, employees
WHERE 
    departments.department_id <> employees.department_id;
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2):

"I want to print all departments that have employees"

```
-- I want to print all departments
SELECT * 
FROM departments d
WHERE EXISTS (
   -- that have employees
   SELECT *
   FROM employees e
   WHERE e.department_id = d.department_id
   );
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution:

```
select * from departments 
where department_id in (select department_id from employees)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need all the departments referenced in the Employees table. 
So you need to go over every employee record whose department_id is not null. Then you have a department that has an employee related.

```
SELECT
    d.department_id,
    d.department_name
FROM
    departments d
JOIN employees e ON e.department_id = d.department_id
WHERE e.department_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY d.department_id
```

Comment: JOINS doesn't join if the referenced key is NULL, so the WHERE sentence in this case is unnecessary.

Comment: Could this be more performance-wise, reducing the data to be joined to only those records that will have a match ?

Comment: The WHERE sentences perform the filtering once the joins are ready. So there should not be any performance improvement. Furthermore, the WHERE will not find NULLs since they where discarded by the JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
DISTINCT d.department_id
FROM
    departments d
JOIN employees e ON e.department_id = d.department_id
```